# Usage of "～だぴょん"

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

A fair while ago someone said something like `嘘だぴょーん！` in a comment.

But what kind of a connotation and usage does `～だぴょん` have? Can it be used in a kind of humorous sort of way?

**Edit:** Realized it was actually `嘘だぴょーん！`.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't だぴょん? It sounds cute since ぴょんぴょん is the way that a bunny bounces. If so, then it is the same as だよん or just だよ.

Comment: @Dono Thanks, yeah I think it actually was `だぴょーん！` rather than `だびょーん！`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was revised since my initial comment, which I will add as an answer.

だぴょん (or だぴょーん) is a final suffix equivalent to だよん or だよ. It adds a sense of cuteness owning to the fact that ぴょん (or ぴょんぴょん) is the way in which something (such as a bunny) hops or bounces.

Answer (score 1):

(@Dono's correction/answer allowed me to find out a lot more, so I thought I might try to add a bit about the expression `嘘ぴょん`.)

According to Zokugo-dict, [`嘘ぴょん`](http://zokugo-dict.com/03u/usopyon.htm) is an expression which first appeared around 1986, and it's used when speaking one's mind after someone tells a fib. It apparently isn't used for really serious lies, only for exaggerations/dramatizations etc which could end up as jokes.

Apparently `嘘ピョーン` was at number 1 at Goo's 2009 [`今でもつい使ってしまう死語ランキング`](http://ranking.goo.ne.jp/ranking/999/dead_language/) "ranking of dead language which is unintentionally used even now."